# Doxygen: document functions that have the same name

Tags: c, doxygen

I've a file structure as followed:

- modules

  - module1

    - module1.c
  - module2

    - module2.c
  - module3

    - module3.c
  - ...

Each `moduleX.c` file contains a function `void test(int param1, int param2)` since the modules can exist on their own. But each function has its own specific module implementation and thus needs its own documentation.

Now, when I ask Doxygen to start generating documentation starting recursively from the top folder `modules`, it doesn't generate documentation for the function `test()` that returns in each module.

How can I force Doxygen to generate the documentation?

Comment: Have you tried using `\defgroup` and related commands?

Comment: I tried them, but it doesn't solve my issue. It just causes Doxygen to generate a list of modules with a *test()* function for each module, without any comments.